# Auto play paused video element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, automation, html5-video

Here is a website link https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/manhattan-pier-southside/5842041f4e65fad6a7708907 which shows camera live footage of some places, when you turn on fullscreen of that video and let it play for around 8 minutes after that the footage becomes blurry and stops playing, and when we go out of fullscreen of the video shows Are you still watching dialog box , when i click the button it is continues playing or in the full screen when i click the video it continues playing
[image]

**What did I want to accomplish?**
I'm trying to create a chrome extension which does the reloading or playing of the video again without leaving the fullscreen 24 hours seperate montior is allocated to this or somehow stops this functionality of the website to remind the user

**what I tried?**
I tried to use `document.querySelector("video").play()`
I thought this may be due to inactivity so I constantly set a interval in like 1 minutes delay to pause and play the video to mimic the user activity

```
setInterval(()=>{
let video = document.querySelector('video');
video.pause();
setTimeout(()=>{video.play()},2000);
},60000);
```

I tried to click the video in fullscreen

```
 let video = document.querySelector('video');
video.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
```

I tried to click the parent element of these video element

what can I do next ?
**I have been banging my head around this for 3 days, MY LAST HOPE IS YOU GUYS I"M BELIVEING YOU GUYS LIKE A MOUNTAIN THANK YOU**

Comment: Try to dispatch MouseDown/MouseUp or Space KeyDown/KeyUp event.

Comment: You can't automate against the auto play feature. That's the whole point. However you should be able to auto-play after click the button once. Is that not the case ?

Comment: also I think you need to add the autoplay attribute to the video element

Comment: The thing is I don't want to click the button "are you still watching" when we are on fullscreen the screen becomes blurry once we click it plays